# Trying to install cx-Freeze but nothing seems to happen

Tags: python, python-3.x

I watched the instructional video here to install cx_Freeze.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J81JFwqsS5o

It seems like the guy runs an executable to do the install.  I downloaded the whl file from here.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze/5.1.1

I run it this way: `pip install some-package.whl`

I am using the Anaconda command prompt and Spyder 3.2.4.  How can I actually install and/or run cx_Freeze?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install` should work fine. The actual way of testing the library would be to import and see the version.

If you wanted to create an executable using cx_freeze, try the setup script in the following link:

https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html